# How to get `git grep` to show `git blame`-like information

Tags: git, git-blame, git-grep

I'd like to `git grep` in the usual way, but with something like the additional insight of `git blame` in the displayed results.

In some instances I probably would benefit from including the metadata in the search query (show only results written by Bob), and in others I'd rather just use my own human judgement.  I guess I'm flexible with which way that goes.

Comment: Grep can't show blame-like information because it does not peruse previous commits line by line the way blame does. So if you have some git-grep output that fingers some particular commit, *run `git blame` starting from that commit* as a separate command; you'll find what you need. Note that there are options to `git blame` to make it possible to use it from scripts, so you may be able build your own command that does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I added the following to my git aliases:

```bash
grame = "!r() { git grep -n $1 $2 | while IFS=: read i j k; do git blame -f -L $j,$j $i; done }; r"
```

Which I shamelessly stole and adapted from:
https://gist.github.com/lonnen/3101795

I added the pathspec argument so it’s used as:

```
git grame <pattern> [<pathspec>...]
```

Note that git blame is called for each match. Since `git blame` can be quite long, if a file has several match, the repeated call can be quite costly. Better try something like:

```bash
grame1 = "!r() { git grep -noh $1 $2 | while IFS=: read line _; do echo -n \"-L ${line},${line} \"; done }; r"
grame2 = "!r() { git grep -l $1 $2 | while IFS=EOL read src; do git blame -f $(git grame1 $1 $src) $src; done }; r
```

but which still does 2 `git grep` call instead of one. Some awk/sed/perl invocation could format the first invocation of `git grep` as:

```
-L line,line -L line,line [as many -L as matches] file
```

Comment: This works to print the filename before each match: `grame = "!r() { git grep -n $1 $2 | while IFS=: read i j k; do echo $i; git blame -f -L $j,$j $i; done }; r"`